# Is there a way to find that a table in page is a dataTable object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am looking for a way to get to know if the tables in a page are dataTable or not? Is there an easy way to find it? Or may be if I can get all the objects of dataTable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($('table').parents('.dataTable_wrapper').length>= 1) {
 do something...
}
```

It's a bit of a hack but there isn't yet a native way to check for a datatable instance. This is something I just so happen to have learned yesterday.

Comment: That hack will work but I was looking for a more robust solution.

Comment: That solution was from this thread on the datatabes forum, http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/7748/check-if-dom-table-is-datatable-instance/p1, the answer came from the creator of datatables himself, so unfortunately I don't think there are many other ways to get it done.

Comment: I am actually looking for dataTable object so that I can call some function on it.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But I think there is no way to find it currently.

Comment: A new static API has been added as mentioned by @Roy Ling's answer. This Api should be used.

Answer (score 12):

There's a static method in the DataTables plugin, so you may verify as:

```
$('table').each(function() {
    // this method accepts the DOM node (table element) as parameter
    if ( $.fn.dataTable.fnIsDataTable(this) ) {
         // do your thing to the table
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to get all the tables on the page that are DataTables in one fell swoop with. The code for DataTables 1.10 would be:

```
$.fn.dataTable.tables()
```

Here's the [doc](http://datatables.net/reference/api/%24.fn.dataTable.tables%28%29) for it. This will return an array of **DOM elements**. If you want to get the DataTable API instances that are associated with them, you can do:

```
var tables = $.fn.dataTable.tables();
var datatables = $(tables).DataTable();
```

Note that although calling `.DataTable()` like above can *create* a new DataTable API instance and consequently initialize your table, if the DOM element(s) for which the method is called *already* have their own instances (the API has already been created and initialized), the call will *not* create new instances. In other words, the code above will not initialize your tables anew.

The `datatables` object here is an API instance that controls the *whole collection* of tables. Calling the API functions on this instance will control all the tables at once. Adapting an example from the documentation, this code:

```
datatables.page('next').draw(false);
```

would make all the tables jump to their next page (if it exists).

In versions prior to 1.10, the equivalent function was `$.fn.dataTable.fnTables`.

Roy Ling mentioned `$.fn.dataTable.fnIsDataTable` that can be used to test tables individually. Of course, in 1.10 it is *still* possible to test tables individually when needed, the function is [`$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/%24.fn.dataTable.isDataTable%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

I know it may be a while since this question was posted, but as I was asking the same question myself, I came to this solution from the DataTable reference [site](https://datatables.net/reference/api/$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable()).

Here's how to check if #example is a DataTable or not. If not, initialise:

```
if ( ! $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#example' ) ) {
    $('#example').dataTable();
}
```

Hope this helps someone!